# Android camera surfaceTexture - How to preserve previous frames?

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, textures

I'm using SurfaceTexture for live camera preview. This sends the data stream directly to the GPU as a texture.

This texture gets overwriten with each new camera frame coming in.

**Now - I want to avoid this overwriting and retain last several(n) previous frames in the memory (which is my ultimate goal here)**

The data from the camera coming in would always overwrite the oldest texture from the n amount of textures available. I just need to alternate between them.

These textures need to be available for immediate rendering as the data are coming in.

I dont need: to save captured data as byte buffer and convert it back to new texture = slow, all must be in real time. Performance is a key here.

I have used this program example to run the camera in surfaceTexture mode: http://maninara.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/render-camera-preview-using-opengl-es.html

I have tried to attach a new texture using attachToGLContext(int texName) method of SurfaceTexture class, but it doesnt seem to allow me to do that without destroying the previous one, seems like i must use "detachFromGLContext()" before attaching a new one..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How do you send the data stream to a texture?

In my case, I create multiple textures in `onSurfaceCreated`. Then overwrite them in `onDraw`. The whole process is real-time and does not need the framebuffer to store the data.

In `onDraw`, I use `glActiveTexture` and `glBindTexture` to choose the texture I want to overwrite. 
Here is the code, hope it helps.

`GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 + texture_index);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture[texture_index]);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, m_frame.width, m_frame.height, 0,  GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, camera_data);`

Comment: The live texture is fed by .updateTexImage(). So In summary?: 1. onDraw: use glGenTextures to reserve free slots for the textures to be saved in. 2. Stream from camera preview is coming in form of a texture, not as an image data (GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, hTex[0]). Therefore i will use glGetTexImage to get the reference to the image data (you called it "camera_data"), using this: glGetTexImage(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0, format, type, camera_data)) 3. Following your steps. Does it look right?Will the next frame not overwrite the texture we just saved?

Comment: Now important for me to distinguish what happens here?: Lets say that the data of one image is 3MB. When tha camera feeds the preview texture, it moves the 3MB to the GPU only once per frame and renders: (Camera capture -> move 3MB -> GPU render ). When we do all this frame preserving, are we: Moving around the references to the 3MB data? (which is exactly what i wanted) Like this: (Camera capt. -> move 3MB -> GPU rend. -> get ref. to the 3MB & preserve) Or are we moving the actual 3MB more than once? Like this: (Camera capture -> move 3MB -> GPU rend. -> Move 3MB to tex. again) Thx

Comment: 1. Yes, use glGenTextures to reserve free slots for the textures to be saved in. 2. I have not used glGetTexImage before, I think your way is right. 3. Use glActiveTexture and glBindTexture to choose the slot you want to overwrite on. Therefore, you can reserve the slots you don't want to overwrite on. 4. I think the process of (move 3MB -> get texture) happens when you call glGetTexImage, so if not called glGetTexImage again on same frame, moving 3MB will be done once on per frame.

Comment: From searching around, looks like the glGetTexImage and glTexImage2D copy all the image data (moving the 3MB around). 
Please allow me some time to experiment with these, as I'm not very proficient with opengl yet. 
I will test these, and if the method doesn't degrade the performance too much, it will be suitable option me, I will therefore accept your answer, otherwise I may look for other options how to point the 3MB data instead of moving it around.
Thanks for help.

Comment: The trouble with the method you have suggested is that I have to somehow extract Bytebuffer data from the cam. texture before i create another, glTexImage2d requires it as an input. I have found out that glGetTexImage is not specified by GLES20, so the only options to extract buffer from tex. is using glReadPixels and then use glteximage2d to create new texture, but thats double the work.

Comment: Also I'm exploring the possibility of rendering texture to texture using FBO+DBO:
http://blog.shayanjaved.com/2011/05/13/android-opengl-es-2-0-render-to-texture/ ,but this way im getting memory issues. two 2048px textures will make the "rendering to texture" crash. Joggling with 7-8 textures of 1024px seems to work, but i need 2048px ones.             Do you have any other idea?